# Laravel cashier update subscription with multiple items

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I have created a subscription on stripe in which users can choose multiple products and quantities for the products.

I am able to create the subscription with multiple items with cashier like below

```
$user->newSubscription('default', ['price_XXXXXXX', 'price_YYYYYYYYY'])
    ->quantity(5, 'price_XXXXXXX')
    ->quantity(10, 'price_YYYYYYYYY')
    ->checkout([
            'success_url' => $successUrl?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            'cancel_url' => $nancelUrl,
        ]);
```

I need the functionality of updating the subscription items in my application. But I am not able to update the quantities of multiple items in a single request.

Cashier has the below function which will update a single item.

```
$subscription->updateQuantity(40, "price_XXXXXXXXXX");
```

which will generate a separate invoice for each item update.

But I want to update multiple items quantities in a single request and it should come under a single payment.

Thanks in advance